# Read More than millions record in cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I am using Cassandra for storing all the events happening my application.After 6 month It has more than millions data.

I am getting following error while reading all the records from cassandra

CLI -

```
cqlsh> use abc;
cqlsh:abc> select count(*) from interaction;
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=localhost
```

From spring data  ( Using allow filtering )

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:69)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36)
    at com.germinait.replica.CassandraTransfer.startTransfer(CassandraTransfer.java:43)
    at com.germinait.replica.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:22)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:673)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:69)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:94)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:235)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:379)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:584)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:
```

I am not sure how to read a large number of data.

Let me know how to read such large data using spring-data or some alternative.

Comment: Cassandra is good at returning values for a specific key or range.  It is not good at returning millions of rows.  In fact, unbound queries are an anti-pattern.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394382/operation-time-out-error-in-cqlsh-console-of-cassandra/29394935#29394935 if that helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Change and see your driver read timeout

https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/socket_options/

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
    .withSocketOptions(
            new SocketOptions()
                    .setConnectTimeoutMillis(2000))
    .build();
```

2. Change Cassandra server configuration to allow large read and writes

> read_request_timeout_in_ms, range_request_timeout_in_ms,
>   write_request_timeout_in_ms, cas_contention_timeout_in_ms,
>   truncate_request_timeout_in_ms

Also, look at this answer for more information.

[Cassandra read timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242177/cassandra-read-timeout)

Comment: I tried this solution.It is returning result set but its very huge to process with java . I am looking for pagination kind of solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many row a table contains, 
you can have a counter table that it's incremented when record is inserted and decremented when rows are deleted.